# Foundation 6 Reveal Modal Cause Unwanted Scroll on Close

Tags: dom-events, foundation

I have multiple modals on a page built using foundation-sites v6.6.3,

modals close fine if clicked outside of.

however, when I hit the "close" button or "ESC" key to close the modal, the modal cloese, but the page always get shifted to the top. How can I prevent the page from shifting.

here's my code for the modal.

```
<!-- trigger button -->
<button class="button" data-open="reveal-com-stem">Hear from a scholarship recipient</button>

<!-- modal window -->
<div class="reveal large" data-animation-in="slide-in-down fast" data-animation-out="scale-out-down fast" data-deep-link="true" data-reveal="" id="reveal-com-stem">
    <div class="row grid-padding-x grid-padding-y">
        (modal content)
    </div>
    <button aria-label="Close modal" class="close-button" data-close="" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&#215;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I've tried to put the following callback on the modal close event

```
$(document).on('closed.zf.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
   $('.reveal').foundation('_disableScroll', 0);
});
```

was hoping to disable the scroll when Reveal closes, but didn't work. Could it be some other DOM elements that's interfering with the close button behavior?